# SSIS Guarantee that all data will be moved to target when running data flows in parallel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, import, etl, ssis-2014

My package has the following two tasks which run in parallel.
[image]

`DF - Move source data to target` loads a copy of all source data to target via `OLEDB Dest - Target` and also loads a copy of source PK values to a staging table via `OLEDB Dest - SourceRowsToDelete`. The staging data is used by `ExecSQL - Delete Source Data` to delete all source data in parallel.

The `OLEDB Dest - SourceRowsToDelete` destination always completes before the `OLEDB Dest - Target` destination.

[image]

`ExecSQL - Delete Source Data` deletes all source data using the following SQL

```
DELETE  sd
FROM    [Source].dbo.[SourceData] sd
INNER JOIN
        [Source].dbo.SourceRowsToDelete s
        ON  sd.ID = s.ID
```

If the rows to be moved are currently in the buffers, have been written to the `[source].dbo.sourcerowstodelete` table and subsequently deleted from source but not yet fully written to target. Other than me stopping the package and dropping the buffers, is there any other way that they won't make it to the target?